# How to create an ArrayList of Classes?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have some classes (`Car`, `Motorcycle`, `Train` ... etc) that extends from `class Vehicle`.
From another Class I need to create an `ArrayList` of Classes for access only to those that inlude the `ArrayList`.

The concept is similar to this, but obviously it doesn't work;

```
ArrayList<Class> vehicleType=new ArrayList<Class>();
vehicleType.add(Class.forName("train"));
```

How can I solve it ? 
Thanks

Comment: There's no reason why this shouldn't work. What error messages, if any, are you getting?

Comment: Class.forName("Train") perhaps? Case sensitive?

Comment: I'm not familiar with java, but does `ArrayList<Vehicle>` do what you want?

Comment: Maybe the class name is `Train` and your `forName()` call specified `train`, which doesn't match in the first letter?

Comment: @ MD: That would give you an array of actual vehicle objects, not Classes.  Im not sure why someone would want a list of Classes, but it is certainly different.

Comment: mmm.. I don't want to do an Array of Vehicles. My idea is to do an arraylist of classes. In a method in other class i will work only with the Classes included in that array.

Comment: A warning is not a problem. To get it to actually work, follow Dave's answer. I guess the warning you get is about the unparameterized Class reference. Use this: `ArrayList<Class<? extends Vehicle>>`.

Comment: Yes G_H, that's the warning; Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> shuld be parameterized. Brilliant G_H, the warning has dissapeared. Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most answers follow your suggestion of using `Class.forName()`, though that's not necessary. You can "call" `.class` on the type name.

Take a look at this JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testListOfClasses() {

    List<Class<?>> classList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

    classList.add(Integer.class);
    classList.add(String.class);
    classList.add(Double.class);

    assertTrue("List contains Integer class", classList.contains(Integer.class));
}
```

I would expect for your need the list would be of type `Class<? extends Vehicle>`

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use the class loader (`Class.forName`), you need to use the fully qualified class name, i.e. `Class.forName("com.package.Train");`, exactly as you would reference it from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends Vehicle>> vehicleType=new ArrayList<? extends Vehicle>();
vehicleType.add(Train.class);
```

It will make sure that all classes added to `vehicleType` extend `Vehicle`. And, that class `Train` actually exists.

It's rarely necessary to use classes that way. Try finding a simpler way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Class.forName("Train") perhaps? Case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

If "train" is the simple class name then this will do the job

> vehicleType.add(Class.forName(train.class.getName()));

Anyway while you don't tell us what is the error (or exception) message we cannot help further.